# Можно ли при помощи flexbox сделать так, чтобы колонки занимали всю свободное пространство, если есть такая возможность?

Tags: css, flexbox

Можно ли при помощи flexbox сделать так, чтобы колонки занимали всю свободное пространство, если есть такая возможность? К примеру, как на картинке - [image: введите сюда описание изображения], у третьего элемента малая ширина, она может занять свободное пространство после первого элемента. Есть способы?

Comment: Flexbox такого не умеет. Поэтому, или JS + Masonry, или `display: grid;` + `grid-auto-flow: dense;`

Comment: Не могу точно сказать, не увидев код, но попробуйте `align-items: stretch`

Answer (score 0):

> Можно ли при помощи flexbox сделать так, чтобы колонки занимали всю свободное пространство, если есть такая возможность?

Например есть такой вариант...

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid;
}
p {
  flex-grow: 999;
  margin: 5px;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Big Title</p>
  <p>None</p>
</div>
```